# R dataframe subset one column to a dataframe (not to a vector)

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a simple `x` dataframe

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(20, 1), ncol = 3)
colnames(x) <- c("one", "two", "three")
x <- as.data.frame(x)
```

I would like to subset the first column of the x dataframe to a dataframe object.

If I do `x[,1]`  I get a vector. However, I want to get a dataframe.

Is there a simple way to transform it to a 1 column dataframe instead and keeping the colname as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can either use without any `,` to preseve the `data.frame` structure

```
x[1]
```

or if we use `,`, `drop=FALSE` argument should be there as the default is `drop = TRUE`.  In the `subset` it is `drop=FALSE` as the default case.

```
x[,1, drop = FALSE]
```